# Print all type of views to PDF report Odoo 13

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, odoo, jspdf

I need to print a PDF report from all views (FORM, TREE, KANBAN, PIVOT, GRAPH, Calendar) in Odoo v13. I found this module

views to pdf
[1]: https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/views2pdfV12/

It's for v12, now I am trying to upgrade it to v13. I have edited the manifest file And also did some modifications to the assets & view XML files, there are also 3 js files that I don't know where to edit. The module was installed successfully without any errors but the button that supposes to show up in the views(FORM, TREE, KANBAN, PIVOT, GRAPH, Calendar) to print the PDF file doesn't show up. What I am missing here & where else could I change to make this work? this is the  assets file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<odoo>
<data>
    <template id="assets_backend" name="popup_reminder assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">

            <!-- css -->

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/views2pdf/static/src/css/views2pdf.css"/>

            <!-- js -->

            <script type="text/javascript" src="/views2pdf/static/src/js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/views2pdf/static/src/js/saveSvgAsPng.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/views2pdf/static/src/js/views2pdf.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</data>
</odoo>
```

and this is the view file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
<template>


<!-- extend FormView widget -->

<t t-extend="FormView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="div.o_form_buttons_view" t-operation="append">
        <button type="button" id="create_pdf" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
            Print
            <span class="fa fa-print"></span>
        </button>
    </t>
</t>

<!-- extend ListView widget -->

<t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="div.o_list_buttons" t-operation="append">
        <button type="button" id="create_pdf" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
            Print
            <span class="fa fa-print"></span>
        </button>
    </t>
</t>

<!-- extend KanbanView widget -->

<t t-extend="KanbanView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="div" t-operation="append">
        <button type="button" id="create_pdf" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
            Print
            <span class="fa fa-print"></span>
        </button>
    </t>
</t>

<!-- extend PivotView widget -->

<t t-extend="PivotView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="button[title='Download xls']" t-operation="after">
        <button type="button" id="create_pdf" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
            Print
            <span class="fa fa-print"></span>
        </button>
    </t>
</t>

<!-- extend GraphView widget -->

<t t-extend="GraphView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="button[data-mode='pie']" t-operation="after">
        <button type="button"  id="create_pdf" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
            Print
            <span class="fa fa-print"></span>
        </button>
    </t>
</t>

<!-- extend CalendarView widget -->

 <t t-extend="CalendarView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="div.o_calendar_buttons" t-operation="append">
        <button type="button" id="create_pdf" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
            Print
            <span class="fa fa-print"></span>
        </button>
    </t>
</t>


 </template>

 </odoo>
```

Comment: The module installs without any error. The print button is visible in the view buttons section and prints the view, but includes the search panel

Comment: @Kenly yeah now it's visible, but when I click nothing happens.  If I add a search panel, is that make it work?

Comment: there are already search panels in the employee module for employees also when I click the button nothing gets printed.

Comment: I mentioned the search panel because I found it unnecessary to show it on PDF. Check the developer console if there is an error.

Comment: nothing in the console everything seems fine, is there any sort of change in the js files?

Comment: I used the same code in a newly installed odoo 13 db and the print button works

Comment: without any kind of modifications? @Kenly

Comment: Yes, check the OCA [Migration-to-version-13.0](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/wiki/Migration-to-version-13.0) to know what you need do to migrate a module to Odoo v13. There is only few changes in JavaScript

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but could you please tell me what are these changes or where to change cus I have spent the whole day trying but to no avail.

Comment: I just downloaded the module from Odoo apps and renamed it to `views2pdf`. Use the OCA guidelines, they added `In JavaScript` to highlight the JavaScript changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248404/discussion-between-sh-eb-and-kenly).